# How can I remove a columns default value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have a bunch datetimes attributes on several databases. This is an example how they are created.

```
ALTER TABLE TripEvent ADD CompleteTime DATETIME DEFAULT '1899-12-31' ;
```

So the column allow null values but the default value is '1899-12-31'.
I want to change that from a DBscript so default value is NULL.
I found this [blog](http://bypsoft.blogspot.fi/2007/10/changing-default-column-values-sql.html). Ok so a default value is stored in a constraint.
My question is, how can I get the name of the constraint to drop ?

Comment: Next time, remember to name the constraint when you add it (`ALTER ... DATETIME constraint DF_TripEvent_CompleteTime default ...`)

Answer (score 0):

Just dropping the constraint is sufficient to make the default null - e.g. don't have a default.

You should be able to find the constraint by running this query (assuming dbo schema, included in the where clause just in case it's not):

```
SELECT default_constraints.name
FROM   sys.all_columns
       INNER JOIN sys.tables
               ON all_columns.object_id = tables.object_id
       INNER JOIN sys.schemas
               ON tables.schema_id = schemas.schema_id
       INNER JOIN sys.default_constraints
               ON all_columns.default_object_id = default_constraints.object_id
WHERE  schemas.name = 'dbo'
       AND tables.name = 'TripEvent'
       AND all_columns.name = 'CompleteTime'
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
ALTER TABLE TripEvent
DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint name found above>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 SELECT def.name AS NameofConstraint,def.type_desc,col.name AS ColName FROM 
  sys.default_constraints def
  INNER JOIN sys.all_columns col ON def.parent_object_id=OBJECT_ID('TripEvent')
  AND col.name='CompleteTime' AND
  col.default_object_id = def.OBJECT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this query to get the default constraints.

```
select * from sysobjects o 
inner join syscolumns c
on o.id = c.cdefault
inner join sysobjects t
on c.id = t.id
where o.xtype = 'D'
and c.name = 'Column_Name'
and t.name = 'Table_Name'
```